# How do I install a Bluetooth headset on a Windows 7 PC to use with Skype?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I'm having trouble installing Nokia BH-100U on my Windows 7 PC (x64). I wanted to use it as a wireless headset for Skype. Currently I'm stuck at the step where the device should be automatically installed by Win7. It doesn't find the appropriate drivers and shows the following message:

[image]

And this is what I get after selecting both Headset and Handsfree telephony services:

[image]

Naturally, the headset doesn't appear in audio devices list.

I tried deleting/removing it and reinstalling again, and the result is still the same as the first time. My usb-bluetooth dongle for PC can handle a PS4 controller, so it shouldn't be the cause. I also tried installing the headset on my netbook which has a built-in wireless module, but with the same result as on desktop PC. And I tried installing it on the WM6.1 smartphone, which worked just fine. Still, I'd like to find a way to use the bluetooth headset with a Win7 PC.

There doesn't seem to exist a separate installation of a "Bluetooth Peripheral Device" driver or anything. It's supposed to be found automatically, but it's not.

I also tried installing a Windows Mobile Device Center which didn't help. There was also a suggestion to get a similar thing intended for Vista x32 but it didn't even want to install on my Win7 x64.

Comment: Click the "Properties" button where you should be able to find detailed information about the devices. Can you look for a "Hardware ID". This will tell you precisely what the missing device is and a Google search may give you clues as to what drivers are needed :)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't really help. The hardware id is for generic bluetooth radio devices.

Comment: Try downloading IVT BlueSoleil BlueTooth: I've read this: http://blog.thepcmechanic.org/?p=74 see if it gives you any progress

Comment: Try [this article](http://www.komeil.com/blog/install-csr-bluetooth-driver-headset-windows-7) on how to add the missing headset profile to the default Microsoft stack. As a long shot you could try [this driver](http://www.myblog.bloggybloggy.com/nokia-bh-105-driver-windows-7-64-bit-06-01-2011/).

Comment: @harrymc the second link's driver worked perfectly! You could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed using the drivers from the article
[Nokia BH-105 Driver for Windows 7](http://www.myblog.bloggybloggy.com/nokia-bh-105-driver-windows-7-64-bit-06-01-2011/),
which in this case worked also for the Nokia BH-100U.

> had problems making the device talk to my Windows 7 (64 bit) because
>   of driver issues, windows tries to install the drivers but they do not
>   work. Download the driver for nokia bh-105 headset below , unzip it
>   and browse to the folder when searching for driver on local drive.
>   Worked like a charm without any issues. Now have bluetooth enabled
>   headset that will work with Skype, Yahoo or Google voice/call etc..
>
> [Download Nokia BH-105 Driver for Windows 7 64 bit](http://www.bloggybloggy.com/randomdownloads/Nokia-BH-105-x64.zip).
>
> Added 32 Bit drivers as well for Nokia BH-105 in case someone
>   is using Windows 7 32 bit still.
>
> [Download Nokia BH-105 Driver for Windows 7 32 Bit](http://www.bloggybloggy.com/randomdownloads/NokiaBH-105Windows32bit.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Toshiba has built the generic drivers for almost any bluetooth devices.
You can download it here- [Toshiba Bluetooth Stack](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Remote-Utils/Toshiba-Bluetooth-Stack.shtml)

Comment: It might be better if you found a link on the official toshiba site ....

Comment: Here's the toshiba support website link for Toshiba Bluetooth Stack
http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3461138

Answer (score -1):

I was having problems with my Bluetooth headset until I updated the drivers with [SlimDrivers](https://www.slimwareutilities.com/slimdrivers.php). It found new drivers that worked with my device.